# Can I downgrade from SQL Server 2017 CU25 to CU20?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, memory-optimized-tables, downgrade, cumulative-update

New instance of SQL Server 2017. I chose to install up to CU25 during the initial installation. Been using the database for a few months, but it seems to have a memory leak when using memory-optimized tables which causes it to crash overnight sometimes.

I have another instance with the same jobs and hardware on CU20 and it has never had this problem. Leads me to believe this is a CU25 issue.

I'd like to downgrade to CU20 to see if this fixes the issue. What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: Why not just spin up another (development) instance of 2017 CU20, and do a backup restore (or however you'd prefer to copy the data over) to it, to see if the problem replicates. Conversely, you can also spin up another CU25 instance as well and see if the problem is replicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The instructions for uninstalling CU25 can be found on the [support page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5003830-cumulative-update-25-for-sql-server-2017-357b80dc-43b5-447c-b544-7503eee189e9) for that cumulative update:

> #### How to uninstall this update on Windows
>
> 1. In Control Panel, open the **Programs and Features** item, and then select **View installed updates**.
> 2. Locate the entry that corresponds to this cumulative update package under **SQL Server 2017**.
> 3. Press and hold (or right-click) the entry, and then select **Uninstall**.

For Linux, follow the instructions at [Rollback SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup?view=sql-server-ver15#rollback).

It is quite unusual to rollback a cumulative update. Be certain that is your best troubleshooting option before committing to it. You might want to do other troubleshooting or contact Microsoft Support about your issue on CU25 instead.

Comment: This worked. I hadn't been clicking on "view installed updates" so I thought there was no way to uninstall. Had forgotten that I'd installed the CU25 update a few days after the initial installation. Thanks!